# Ubuntu 16.10 or 17.04 when shuting down 5 "Failed " errors are reported

Tags: encryption, shutdown

I am not sure if this indicates a serious bug. When shutting down I see 5 lines with *"FAILED" stopped with error*.

```
[FAILED] Stopped (with error) /dev/dm-0.
[FAILED] Stopped (with error) /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-CRYPT-PLAIN-cryptswmp1
[FAILED] Stopped (with error) /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-cryptswmp1
[FAILED] Stopped (with error) /dev/disk/by-uuid/99c89684-2f0d-4a87-b7d2-696b4fa6ed09
[FAILED] Stopped (with error) /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-0
```

Comment: Any solution?? I am facing the same problem in ubuntu 17.04

Comment: It seems that this is a [bug in systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1620) when systemd tries to unmount a cryptswap partition. I updated to systemd 234 and then didn't see the issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in systemd, here's my work around.

```
root@x360:~# cat /lib/systemd/system-shutdown/fix-shutdown-errors.sh 
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/swapoff -a
/sbin/cryptsetup luksClose mmc_crypt
/sbin/cryptsetup luksClose sda5_crypt
```